# I don't understand pointers, addresses and scopes

Tags: c, pointers

Following is a code snippet, I have written and I am currently struggling with my print-outs.

In my main method I call the function `insertPoint` twice with valid input, for example: `insertPoint(42); insertPoint(56);` and get the following output:

```
A.1 42
B.3 2686700
```

At B.3 however I would expect it to also return the value 42, but it doesn't. I assume 2686700 refers to some address in the memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

struct point {
    int value;
    struct point* next;
};

struct point *root;

int insertPoint(int value) {            
    // Graph is empty, set new root 
    if(root == 0){
        struct point newRoot;
        newRoot.value = value;

        root = &newRoot;
        (*root).value = value;
        printf("A.1 %d \n", (*root).value); // "A.1 42"
        return value;
        }
    printf("B.3 %d \n", (*root).value); // "B.3 2686700"

    /* rest of code here; irrelevant since related variables are not changed */
}
```

Does someone have an idea why this happens? Any constructive comment/answer is appreciated.

I would also appreciate, if the downvoters would provide me feedback, why they found my question inappropriate.

Comment: `(*root).value = value;` - Use `root->value = value` - I find this easier to read and sort of implies the use of a pointer

Answer (score 5):

If the `if (root == 0)` branch is taken, `root` will point to `struct point newRoot;` which is allocated on the stack inside the body of the `if` branch. The `newRoot` structure goes out of scope after leaving the body of the branch and the body of the function, in your case after the `return value;` statement. However, the global pointer variable `root` will keep pointing to that location in memory (on stack). The contents of stack memory at that location will most likely be overwritten by some other code, hence reading a `point` (member) value from that location (e.g. via the `root` pointer) will result in undefined behaviour, which is why you get such results.

You probably meant to dynamically allocate the new root, e.g.:

```
if(root == 0) {
    root = (point *) malloc(sizeof(point));
    root->value = value;
    root->next = NULL;
    printf("A.1 %d \n", root->value); // "A.1 42"
    return value;
}
```

Don't forget to set the `next` pointer, as it will not by default be `NULL` (unless perhaps instead of `malloc` you use `calloc` which zero-initializes the returned memory, effectively making the value of `next` equal to `NULL` on *most* platforms). Additionally, don't forget to deallocate any memory you allocate dynamically: any memory allocate with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` must be deallocated later using `free`.

Comment: Is there any reason to cast malloc ?

Comment: @Michi You mean the `(point *)`? I think it is not required in C because `malloc` returns a `void *` value. However, C++ would require a cast.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has undefined behavior because it lets a pointer to local variable be used outside the scope.

It happens here:

```
struct point newRoot;
...
root = &newRoot;
```

The problem with this is that once the function reaches the `}` closing the `if` statement, `root` becomes invalid. Any dereference of it is undefined behavior. Hence when you do this

```
printf("B.3 %d \n", (*root).value);
```

you access memory pointed to by an invalid pointer.

Fortunately, the fix to this problem is simple: use `malloc` instead of `newRoot` to allocate memory for the linked list element:

```
if(root == 0){
    root = malloc(sizeof(struct point));
    root->value = value;
    printf("A.1 %d \n", (*root).value); // "A.1 42"
    return value;
}
```

Of course you would need to `free` the memory you allocate with `malloc` before exiting the program in order to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

You create `struct point newRoot;` on stack inside a function. Since, it is on stack, it is destroyed on exit from this function. Any use of its pointer (`*root`) should give undefined result after that.

Comment: It was unfair for somebody to downvote you - I have tried to put this right

Answer (score 2):

You must understand that stuff on the stack disappears when it goes out of scope

SO

```
root = &newRoot;
```

Here `newRoot` is on the stack. End of function - End of `newRoot` - So the pointer is invalid

Use `malloc` to create the `newRoot` object so I can live longer that the function call